# How to hide a php file that is being called in ajax post method?

Tags: php, ajax

In my working folder, I have /data/teacherData.php. The teacherData.php has a query that will retrieve data from database and in my index.php I created an ajax post method request that displays the results from teacherData.php. When I go directly to data/teacherData.php it will display the results...

[Here is the data that i want to hide or return to 403](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RLVI5.png)

My question is how can I properly hide and secure this data ? is there something to do with .htaccess ? Any thoughts?

Comment: If it's returning data that you later display, why do you feel you need to secure it?

Comment: How do you suppose you can display the data if you don't want others to get the data when going to the link?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to upload an image, you can guys check it

Comment: It doesn't answer our questions. If you say yourself that you use this data to display it in a page, why would you consider it sensitive? Also, I'm puzzled if you're doing an AJAX **post**, why is a direct browser **get** returning the same results?

Comment: function select_section() {
                        $.ajax({
                            url: 'data/select_section.php',
                            method: 'POST',
                            success: function(data) {
                                $("#select_section").html(data);
                            }
                        });
                    }

It's purpose is to get the data from the url, my concern was whenever i go directly to mysitq.com/data/teacherData.php it will also display results. How can i prevent it? Sorry for misunderstandings

Comment: An alternative to hiding it behind login while still preventing direct access would be only allowing the `POST` method for the given url. How to do that depends heavily on your system (server, hosting, framework...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you will upload your website to hosting, or It is already there , you could make restricted access to that file, so when you go directly to that file it will ask you for login and password. Ajax will be still functional.

Comment: Thanks for response. Do you have any tutorials that I can read or watch?

Comment: Setting password to website or file on server different on each hosting, if you don't know how to do this on your hosting, ask tech support, they will help you

Comment: Don't forget to mark as answer if it helped you, it would help other users with same question

Comment: yeah, Im still looking for possible answers that may help me.